# Nuxtjs is slow loading in npm run dev (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, nuxt.js, localhost, loading

I have a problem, which is that the time to open the page in nuxtjs takes longer than usual. I don’t know what the reason is. Previously, I did not encounter this problem.

In npm run dev

I created a new nuxt project completely free of modifications. The problem is that it takes about 3 seconds to open the page in the Chrome browser, and the loading animation appears.

My device specifications:

i7-10700F

32GB RAM

I tried analyzing the site in the browser :

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrgJv.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c10Wc.png)

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAC6l.png)

The project is completely new

I use Windows, and I don't know if I did something wrong with the device during this period that led to this

..The project is completely new, nothing has been modified